# Adding in a CSS faded border

Tags: css

I was just wondering if anyone might be able to tell me how to add a left and right sided faded border to my webpages such as on this site:

http://www.farrow-ball.com/colours/paint/fcp-category/list?resetFilters=true

My webpages are of a fixed layout and are 920px in width to the edges of the images / text boxes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in my quest to learn CSS! I've tried to find tutorials on how to do this or previous topics on this however I must not be putting in the correct keywords because I can't seem to find what I'm after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use `box-shadow` it's supported in most new browser, some uses prefixes though.

there is even a generator available that can come in handy

http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Comment: That's excellent thank you. I actually gave that a go a while ago but I couldn't get it to be equal on the left and right - it seemed to only be able to be a shadow in one direction. Through using that tool however I found that if I place the shadow centrally and enlarge it with a larger blur then this overcomes that effect. There is still a bottom border on this, and I presume a top as well, although it isn't visible, but this works well in any case! Thanks again!